# Should have subtitle controller already set Mediaplayer error Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Whenever I play a media, it shows a warning in DDMS `Should have subtitle controller already set`

MY CODE:

```
private void start() {
    mediaPlayer.start();

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }
    });
}
```

DDMS LOG

> Should have subtitle controller already set
>
> info/warning (2, 0)

When I searched on Google, not even a single topic related to it. How can I get rid of or disable this?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

A developer recently [added subtitle support to VideoView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/bbf4962%5E%5E1..bbf4962%5E/).

When the [`MediaPlayer`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-cts-4.4_r1/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java) starts playing a music (or other source), it checks if there is a SubtitleController and shows this message if it's not set.
It doesn't seem to care about if the source you want to play is a music or video. Not sure why he did that.

**Short answer:** Don't care about this "Exception".

---

**Edit :**

Still present in [Lollipop](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-release/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java#2033),

If `MediaPlayer` is only used to play audio files and you really want to remove these errors in the logcat, the code bellow set an `empty SubtitleController` to the `MediaPlayer`.

**It should not be used in production environment and may have some side effects.**

```
static MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer(Context context){

    MediaPlayer mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        return mediaplayer;
    }

    try {
        Class<?> cMediaTimeProvider = Class.forName( "android.media.MediaTimeProvider" );
        Class<?> cSubtitleController = Class.forName( "android.media.SubtitleController" );
        Class<?> iSubtitleControllerAnchor = Class.forName( "android.media.SubtitleController$Anchor" );
        Class<?> iSubtitleControllerListener = Class.forName( "android.media.SubtitleController$Listener" );

        Constructor constructor = cSubtitleController.getConstructor(new Class[]{Context.class, cMediaTimeProvider, iSubtitleControllerListener});

        Object subtitleInstance = constructor.newInstance(context, null, null);

        Field f = cSubtitleController.getDeclaredField("mHandler");

        f.setAccessible(true);
        try {
            f.set(subtitleInstance, new Handler());
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {return mediaplayer;}
        finally {
            f.setAccessible(false);
        }

        Method setsubtitleanchor = mediaplayer.getClass().getMethod("setSubtitleAnchor", cSubtitleController, iSubtitleControllerAnchor);

        setsubtitleanchor.invoke(mediaplayer, subtitleInstance, null);
        //Log.e("", "subtitle is setted :p");
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    return mediaplayer;
}
```

This code is trying to do the following from the hidden API

```
SubtitleController sc = new SubtitleController(context, null, null);
sc.mHandler = new Handler();
mediaplayer.setSubtitleAnchor(sc, null)
```

Comment: I agree - it's not an error if a subtitle track doesn't exist. Informational at most.

Comment: ok, sure, but is there an easy way to suppress it? it's junking up my logcat output...

Comment: Can make a filter i think if it's really annoying, recompile android, or setting an empty SubtitleController for your song.

Comment: @Hacketo how do you set an empty SubtitleController?  Sorry I don't see this in the docs.

Comment: Of course the documentation is not providing this information.
If you've seen the code shared of the MediaPlayer you can see that there is a setter for the SubtitleController (so it should be possible), but unfortunately seem unavailable.

Answer (score 9):

To remove message on logcat, i add a subtitle to track.
On windows, right click on track -> Property ->  Details -> insert a text on subtitle.
Done :)

Comment: Couple thoughts on this:  1) modifying source file isn't really feasible in a lot of situations.  2) you didn't explain why adding a subtitle track would fix an error on a subtitle controller in the MediaPlayer.

Comment: The error is "Should have subtitle controller already set", so i add a subtitle to track so avoid this error message.

Comment: subtitle or subtitle controller.  are you saying that by having a subtitle track on a video the media player automatically generates a controller?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can only set `mediaPlayer.reset()` and in `onDestroy` set it to release.