# Android MediaPlayer warning: Should have subtitle controller already set

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

My Nexus 4 got upgraded to 4.4 and now whenever MediaPlayer plays a sound, I get the warning:

```
Should have subtitle controller already set
```

And also when calling `mp.release()` I now get the warning

```
mediaplayer went away with unhandled events
```

The same app on a Nexus 7 with 4.3 doesn't display these warnings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should have subtitle controller already set Mediaplayer error Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087804/should-have-subtitle-controller-already-set-mediaplayer-error-android)

Answer (score 10):

In `Android 4.4` `kitkat`, there is a new feature which supports `WebVTT` for `HLS` which has introduced some changes in `MediaPlayer`. (Reference: [`Kitkat` highlights](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#Multimedia) - Closed Captions)

From your description of the error, it looks like the actual player engine is not invoking `setSubtitleAnchor` as `VideoView` is doing [here](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java#307). This leads to the error message from another method [here](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java#1847) which is invoked as part of the `prepare` state transition before invoking the listener.

**P.S:** Is your player a custom player or a standard player which comes pre-bundled as part of the `Android` distribution? Can you share any further logs?

Answer (score 5):

```
mp.reset();
mp.release();
```

That should help you get rid of the second warning