# MediaPlayer : Should have subtitle controller already set: KitKat

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-4.4-kitkat

I am having an odd issue where my audio file sometimes plays and sometimes does not play.  The catch is that when it decides to not play, the DDMS gives me an:

```
E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
```

Because this is one-to-one with the music not playing, I have determined that this is probably the issue...

If the music is not playing and I hit the volume button it begins to play.
If I wait about 30 seconds of no-play, it begins to start again (not looping).

Whats going on here?  I am on KitKat using

```
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
        try {
            afd = getAssets().openFd("Theme.mp3");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength()); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            player.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        player.setLooping(true); //restart playback end reached
        //player.setVolume(1, 1); //Set left and right volumes. Range is from 0.0 to 1.0
        player.start(); //start play back
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should have subtitle controller already set Mediaplayer error Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087804/should-have-subtitle-controller-already-set-mediaplayer-error-android)

Comment: Sorry to be the useless "me too" but, did you manage to solve it? I am facing the same problem here *only* with 5.0 Lollypop. The same code have never failed before, and doesn't fail in an emulator with 4.4.4.

Comment: Every answer in this question does not work. Don't waste your time. You want this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20149754/1048340

Answer (score 10):

Looking at a [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087804/should-have-subtitle-controller-already-set-mediaplayer-error-android) on StackOverflow, and the referenced [Android commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/bbf4962%5E%5E1..bbf4962%5E/)  where this was introduced, the code above might not completely initialize the `MediaPlayer` object.

The [KitKat example code](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mediaplayer) for media playback suggests that you should call:

```java
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

immediately after you construct the `MediaPlayer`, and before you call its `setDataSource` method.

Comment: This didn't change anything.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's happening then. The log statement should *not* be enough to halt the program on its own; the only Android log that will do this is `Log.wtf`. Perhaps the issue is related to how the code posted above is called?

Comment: Could be. I am running Processing (extends pApplet) and calling the player logic on overritten onStart on destroy onPause ect...

Comment: Although this is more speculative - I've never used Processing - you might look into using the MediaPlayer [asynchronously](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#preparingasync). 

There may be a conflict between the way Processing is trying to handle your app's threads at runtime, and the way the synchronous MediaPlayer calls are expecting them to be handled.

Comment: im using the code that google recommends, including setAudioStreamType() and i still get this error. tried it in the main thread and async. same error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by adding the following right after instantiating MediaPlayer.

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        if (mp == mediaPlayer) {
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Previously I was implementing MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener and overriding onPrepared() but it didn't work.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

This should fix your problem (did for me): Replace the line that says "player.start()" following the rest of your code with an async callback like so:

```
player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

This error is just a Log.e, not a real error. It shouldn't cause your player to not play, I'm guessing it's just because the player hadn't finished preparing when you try to call start().

```
E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
```

Comment: No, this has no impact. I am having the same issue here, and I've code that used to run just fine. Now I get the same halt (of audio, not the app -- app is fine, i can start another audio track for example) right after seeing that error log.

Answer (score -1):

Its been a long time since I was working on this app.  Here is what I ended up doing to get this to work.  (Tested on KitKat and Lollipop).  I think switching from MediaPlayer to APMediaPlayer was part of the trick.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if(player != null) {
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(player != null) {
        player.start();
    }
    else {
        player = new APMediaPlayer(this); //create new APMediaPlayer
        player.setMediaFile("Theme.mp3"); //set the file (files are in data folder)
        player.start(); //start play back
        player.setLooping(true); //restart playback end reached
        player.setVolume(1, 1); //Set left and right volumes. Range is from 0.0 to 1.0
    }

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(player != null) {
        player.start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -12):

set in manifest file may help you

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: This has no impact on the issue provided by the OP.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the question.