# System app with android:persistent="true" lead to Webview's video play black screen

Tags: android, webview, system

I have a system level app with android:persistent="true", which is pushed to /system/priv-app/ directory. So, it will be auto-install and start its process after reboot. But, when I start my WebActivity to load a web url which contains  tag by WebView, it play audio but black screen when press video tag's play button. However, if I remove android:persistent="true", it is ok.

It is confused me  very much, cause sdk document never saied android:persistent may lead to that bug, but it happened.
Below is the log after I press  tag's play button, wish it will be helpful.

```
7-16 11:30:25.678 660-2415/com.example.zhanghq.anytest W/chromium: [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(890)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
07-16 11:30:25.958 660-660/com.example.zhanghq.anytest W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
07-16 11:30:31.898 660-660/com.example.zhanghq.anytest I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.", source:  (0)
07-16 11:30:32.038 660-660/com.example.zhanghq.anytest D/MediaPlayerBridge: setDataSource: http://img-steward-test.goodaa.com.cn/a03848997fae4bb5a35684e7b0284517.mp4
07-16 11:30:32.038 660-660/com.example.zhanghq.anytest D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
07-16 11:30:35.368 660-660/com.example.zhanghq.anytest E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
07-16 11:30:35.558 660-660/com.example.zhanghq.anytest D/MediaPlayer: getMetadata
07-16 11:30:36.588 660-660/com.example.zhanghq.anytest I/MediaPlayer: Info (700,504)
07-16 11:30:37.618 660-660/com.example.zhanghq.anytest I/MediaPlayer: Info (700,902)
07-16 11:30:38.618 660-660/com.example.zhanghq.anytest I/MediaPlayer: Info (700,1259)
07-16 11:30:39.648 660-660/com.example.zhanghq.anytest I/MediaPlayer: Info (700,1615)
07-16 11:30:40.648 660-660/com.example.zhanghq.anytest I/MediaPlayer: Info (700,2014)
07-16 11:30:41.658 660-660/com.example.zhanghq.anytest I/MediaPlayer: Info (700,2338)
07-16 11:30:42.708 660-660/com.example.zhanghq.anytest I/MediaPlayer: Info (700,2685)
07-16 11:30:43.748 660-660/com.example.zhanghq.anytest I/MediaPlayer: Info (700,3074)
07-16 11:30:44.788 660-660/com.example.zhanghq.anytest I/MediaPlayer: Info (700,3431)
07-16 11:30:45.788 660-660/com.example.zhanghq.anytest I/MediaPlayer: Info (700,3829)
07-16 11:30:46.808 660-660/com.example.zhanghq.anytest I/MediaPlayer: Info (700,4205)
07-16 11:30:47.818 660-660/com.example.zhanghq.anytest I/MediaPlayer: Info (700,4604)
```

Comment: *Maybe* similar to this problem occuring from another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790824/mediaplayer-should-have-subtitle-controller-already-set-kitkat).

Comment: It doesn't help