# Android MediaPlayer error (1, -19)

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on an app in which an audio file (boo.wav) is being played. The audio does however not play and generates some error output.

When trying to execute the following line:

```
MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.boo).start();
```

I get the following errors:

```
E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -19)
E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-19)
```

Can someone point me in a general direction as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: see this post, it could help your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087804/should-have-subtitle-controller-already-set-mediaplayer-error-android