# Logcat error E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set

Tags: android

I have a soundboard and when I am debugging it, I get these errors:

> E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set

My log is full of these errors, even though my java has no errors. I'm not sure why but I would like fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Short Answer : **Ignore this exception**

For further info: [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087804/should-have-subtitle-controller-already-set-mediaplayer-error-android) this question.