# Android Studio warning: E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set

Tags: android, android-studio, media-player

I got the error `E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set` when I try to play a sound by clicking a button.

```
    public void clicaSom(View view) {
    MediaPlayer somPickObjeto = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pegaitem);
    somPickObjeto.start();

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should have subtitle controller already set Mediaplayer error Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087804/should-have-subtitle-controller-already-set-mediaplayer-error-android)

Answer (score 0):

This log message is a known API error when playing audio only. You should just ignore it, or if you want to get rid of it there is an example here: [Should have subtitle controller already set Mediaplayer error Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087804/should-have-subtitle-controller-already-set-mediaplayer-error-android)

Comment: Does this mean this question is a duplicate of the one you have found? If so, it should be marked as such

Comment: Yes it is. I wanted to mark it as such, but I can't find how to do it. There used to be a nice button around here somewhere, but I can't seem to find it. If you can, please mark it as duplicate. Thank you.