# android button click sound problems

Tags: android, buttonclick

hello everyones I am making button click sound  but I have this log error

"**Should have subtitle controller already set**"

how can I do that is my code

```
private  MediaPlayer mp;
//on create  code 
mp = MediaPlayer.create(CameraTestActivity.this,R.raw.button);
//and button click code   mp.start();
```

Comment: it is not too big of a problem.When the MediaPlayer starts playing a music (or other source), it checks if there is a SubtitleController and shows this message if it's not set..take a look at this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087804/should-have-subtitle-controller-already-set-mediaplayer-error-android

Comment: I saw this but how to use this function in my code ?  I dont understand