# Mediaplayer Background Audio not work properly Using URL And Song Not Play Second Time

Tags: android

This is my second activity and when open this activity threw button activity take  load and  open after some time and  some times UI Freeze and some time black screen open for some seconds

```
public class AartiActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final MediaPlayer player1 = new MediaPlayer();
    private Button btn_playarti, btn_pausearti, btn_stoparti;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_aarti);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        btn_playarti = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_playarti);
        btn_pausearti = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_pausearti);
        btn_stoparti = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stoparti);

        try {
            player1.setDataSource(STRING_URL);
            player1.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        btn_playarti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                player1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
                        player.stop();
                    }
                });
                player1.start();
            }
        });

        btn_pausearti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (player1.isPlaying()) {
                    player1.pause();
                }
            }
        });

        btn_stoparti.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                player1.stop();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        player1.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide your logcat

Comment: E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087804/should-have-subtitle-controller-already-set-mediaplayer-error-android

Comment: i was tried this method it work but activity take some timmes to open new activity

Comment: Please edit your question and provide your current code and your full logcat.