# Android MediaPlayer: getting Error (1,-1004) on API 19?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am using MediaPlayer to play music from url when my activity start. It works well on API above 19 but not working on API 19 (emulator). **Why is this happening and how to solve it?**

I have searched this problem on stackoverflow, most of the answer suggest that the error is caused by bad connectivity or invalid state (media is being played before prepared), but I did use the `prepareAsync` method and start the audio in `onPrepared` method. I also did the test on other device and emulator (with API above 19) and there is no error occured.

This is my code.

```
private lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer
private var isMediaPrepared: Boolean = false
private val backsoundUrl = "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-8.mp3"

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game)

    mediaPlayer = createPlayer()
    mediaPlayer.apply {
        try {
            setDataSource(backsoundUrl)
            isLooping = true
            setOnPreparedListener { mp ->
                isMediaPrepared = true
                mp.start()
            }
            prepareAsync()
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}

private fun createPlayer(): MediaPlayer {
    return MediaPlayer().apply {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            setAudioAttributes(
                AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                    .build()
            )
        } else {
            setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
        }
    }
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
        mediaPlayer.pause()
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
        mediaPlayer.stop()
    }
    mediaPlayer.reset()
    mediaPlayer.release()
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

**Edit:**
This is my logcat

```
01-20 10:15:52.248 5171-5171/com.example.guessthesound E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
01-20 10:15:52.518 5171-5183/com.example.guessthesound E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -1004)
01-20 10:15:52.518 5171-5171/com.example.guessthesound E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1004)
```

**Edit 2:**

This code used to work on emulator API 21, but now it cannot play the audio and the logcat only show error `E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set`. I read https://stackoverflow.com/a/20149754/11986468 and other similar questions, most of the answer suggest to just ignore it. I don't know if it cannot play the audio because of this error or not but there is no other error. After I found this, I tried to test on device with API 21 and it works well, so may be there's something wrong with the emulator? Is it possible the error on API 19 is because I was using emulator? (I am using Android Studio emulator)

What might be the caused and can this be fixed?

Comment: post your logcat errors here so we can see and help you

Comment: I would like to know, by not playing do you specifically mean that the app is crashing or just that there is no sound? There is a quirk in emulators running 20 or lower is that, if your system sound sources are not setup properly, It would fail to build sound output channels. What I mean is that, check whether you have speakers or headphones connected before running the emulator otherwise you won't be hearing any sound. I don't why it is like this, but I used to have problems of no media audio before discovering this quirk.

Comment: I meant there is no sound but app is not crashing. I checked that it's not even go to onPrepared state so I think the audio can't even play in the first place. If sound sources in emulator API 29 works well, I think there's nothing wrong with the setup(?) and I did increase the volume to 100%. By the way I just tested the app on device API 19 and it still showing same errors. @Arun123